# No Extension Method for AsEnumerable, FirstOrDefault add and remove

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, model-view-controller, web-deployment

```
using EmpSys.DBContext;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
//using System.Data;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace EmpSys.Controllers
{
    public class UserAPIController : BaseAPIController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            return ToJson(EmpDB.TblEmp.AsEnumerable());
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]TblEmp value)
        {
            EmpDB.TblEmp.Add(value);
            return ToJson(EmpDB.SaveChanges());
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, [FromBody]TblEmp value)
        {
            EmpDB.Entry(value).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return ToJson(EmpDB.SaveChanges());
        }
        public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
        {
            EmpDB.TblEmp.Remove(EmpDB.TblEmp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id));
            return ToJson(EmpDB.SaveChanges());
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the above code, I get the following errors:

1. Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   EmpSys

Similarly to add and remove.

2. Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and no extension method 'AsEnumerable' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   EmpSys

What should be done to have a definition for AsEnumerable and FirstOrDefault??

Answer (score 0):

`EmpSys` should be inherited from `IEnumerable`. Check the type of `EmpSys`

Comment: how can I inherit it from IEnumerable?

Comment: EmpSys is an asp.net project in visual studio 2017 with MVC Architecture

Comment: Could you show the definition of  `EmpSys` and `EmpDB`?

Comment: what do you mean by the definition?

Comment: EmpSys is the project name in visual studio